# Replace the plus sign on set -x command prompt

Tags: bash

I use `set -x` in my script to output the lines as they are executed.

I would like to add some comments there, so I use the `:` command, which does nothing

```
: :::: comment here
```

which looks fine, but It would look nicer if the other lines would have a preceding `:` as well, instead of the preceding `+` on each line.

How do I change the plus sign?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the `PS4` shell variable. From `man bash`:

> ```
>   PS4    The value of this parameter is expanded  as  with  PS1  and  the
>           value  is  printed  before  each command bash displays during an
>           execution trace.  The first character of PS4 is replicated  mul‐
>           tiple  times, as necessary, to indicate multiple levels of indi‐
>           rection.  The default is ``+ ''.
> ```

Comment: great solution, I used this now: `PS4="# "; set -x`
`